# Яндекс api (2.1) Уделение всех элементов, кроме полигона?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть карта где выводится полигон, точки, маршруты.
Все добавлеться через `myMap.geoObjects.add();`
И есть табы которые переключают тот или иной вид(точки, марурты и т.д.)
Чтоб менять эти виды, я удаляю все через `myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();` и заново генерирую то что мне нужно. Нужно чтоб при переключении табов, удалялось все, кроме полигона.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете при смене таба удалять не все объекты, а только те, которые на нём создавались и больше не нужны. Для этого доступен [метод `remove()`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObjectCollection-docpage/?from=SO#remove).

Другой вариант - заново добавлять полигон после каждого `removeAll()`, но лучше удалять только лишние.

Comment: ну вот заново я добавляю и происходит как бы мелкое мерцание, хотелось бы от него избавиться, хорошо, а что как писать нужно если использовать просто remove() .myMap.geoObjects.remove() - что-то надо передать в скобки как я понимаю, но что?

Comment: удалять только ненужные объекты правильнее. Там в ответе ссылка на документацию - передать нужно то же название объекта, что и указывали в add.

Comment: Супер, заработало. Спасибо